# English / Swedish translation data?

Tags: data-request, language, translation

I'm looking for a dataset similar to the "parallel data" (i.e. one file is English and one file is Swedish) found in the [WMT translation task](http://www.statmt.org/wmt17/translation-task.html). Their datasets include news commentary, European parliament proceedings, and more. Is there a similar open dataset that has parallel translation data for English and Swedish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [OPUS](http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/), an open parallel corpus.

> OPUS is a growing collection of translated texts from the web. In the OPUS project we try to convert and align free online data, to add linguistic annotation, and to provide the community with a publicly available parallel corpus. OPUS is based on open source products and the corpus is also delivered as an open content package. We used several tools to compile the current collection. All pre-processing is done automatically. No manual corrections have been carried out.

- [Corpus query](http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/bin/opuscqp.pl)

Example - http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/bin/opuscqp.pl?corpus=EMEA;lang=sv

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The term to search for is "parallel corpus".

The most comprehensive resource for Swedish/English seems to be:

**[The English-Swedish Parallel Corpus (ESPC)](http://www.sol.lu.se/engelska/corpus/corpus/espc.html)**

> The current (expanded) version of the ESPC consists of 64 English text samples and their translations into Swedish and 72 Swedish text samples and their translations into English (see Table 1).
>
> The total size of the corpus is 2.8 million words.

Unfortunately, because of copyright, the dataset is not available without a university collaboration. **Boo!**

> The ESPC project has been allowed to store and use the texts under certain strict conditions stated in the permissions from the copyright holders. The corpus can only be used for research. No commercial use is permitted. Moreover, the corpus is only available for research at the Department of English at the Universities of Lund and Göteborg. Scholars and students outside these departments can gain access to the corpus by visiting, or cooperating with, one of these departments.

But that site does [list other resources](http://www.sol.lu.se/engelska/corpus/corpus/websites.html), of which with [help from the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20050224222612/http://www.lpl.univ-aix.fr:80/projects/multext/CORP/DAG.html), turned up a big corpus but unfortunately it seems not parallel languages. Maybe something in [Språkbanken](https://spraakbanken.gu.se/) is useful.